# In x86 assembly, why would reading standard input block the program?

Tags: c, assembly

I'm a newbie to x86 assembly (Intel syntax) and have been playing around with some simple instructions using inline GCC.  I have successfully managed to do manipulation of numbers and control flow and am now tackling standard input and output using interrupts.  I am using Mac OS X and forcing compilation for 32-bit using the `-m32` GCC flag.

I have the following for printing a string to standard output:

```
char* str = "Hello, World!\n";
int strLen = strlen(str);
asm
{
    mov eax, 4
    push strLen
    push str
    push 1
    push eax
    int 0x80
    add esp, 16
}
```

When compiled and run this prints `Hello, World!` to the console!  However, when I try to do some reading from standard input, things don't work as well:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
printf("Please enter your name: ");
asm
{
    mov eax, 3
    push 16
    push str
    push 0
    push eax
    int 0x80
    add esp, 16
}
printf("Hello, %s!\n", str);
```

When run, I get a prompt, but without the "Please enter your name: " string.  When I enter some input and hit Enter, the entry string is printed as well as the expected output, e.g.

```
Please enter your name: Hello, Joe Bloggs
!
```

How do I get the entry string to appear in the expected location, before the user enters any input?

Comment: The inline assembly without clobber lists is extremely worrying...

Comment: @KerrekSB True, but I think in gcc, you can use `asm volatile` to keep the assembly from getting relocated.

Comment: Also, why are you using inline assembly when you could just use `syscall(SYS_read, STDIN_FILENO, str, 16)`? It seems like a much easier way to test out syscalls....

Comment: Please not that this problem is not assembler-specific. Try to replace the assembler code by the following line of C code: "read(0,str,16);" the problem should still remain. In fact, the problem is not in the assembler code but in the "printf()" function. As the other comment says: "fflush(...)" will help.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments!  I have added flush(stdout), and will shortly be looking at clobber lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` writes using stdio, which does buffering (i.e., what's written doesn't get output straight away). You need to call `fflush(stdout)` first, before you send your syscall to read (since syscalls bypass stdio and knows nothing about buffers).

Also, as Kerrek SB has noted, your `asm` does not have a clobber list and it's not `volatile`. That means that gcc is free to relocate your assembly code elsewhere in the function (since it's free to assume your assembly code has no side effects), which may have a different effect from what you expect. I recommend you use `asm volatile`.